# Include reason per certificate when revoking using openssl

Tags: openssl, certificate, certificate-revocation

Is there any way to include a certificate revocation reason? I've found the way to do for the CRL but I want to include one every time I revoke a certificate.

I have tried:

```
openssl ca -revoke jlanza@a.b.es.crt.pem -crl_reason keyCompromise -crl_compromise time 20140314030500Z
```

But it is not included.